# How to create these regex

Tags: regex

I need to create the following regex with ranges

Numbers from 1000 to 1096

```
^10[0-9].....
```

Numbers from 1097 to 1192

```
^10.....
```

Numbers from 1193 to 1288

```
^1[12]....
```

Can you tell me if there is a quick way to do it?

Comment: In general, it's not a good use for regular expressions to determine whether a numeric value is within a range. You can/should use a regular expression to *extract* the number from the string, and then use whatever facilities are available in the parent language to see if the number is within a range.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: it is a telephone app based on asterisk. I do not have control on the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use anything else than regex for that, you should.

If you can't, this regex will match numbers from 1000 to 1096 :

```
10([0-8]\d|9[0-6])
```

This one will match numbers from 1097 to 1192 :

```
1(09[7-9]|1([0-8]\d|9[0-2]))
```

And this one numbers from 1193 to 1288 :

```
1(19[3-9]|2([0-7]\d|8[0-8]))
```

Note that I didn't add any kind of anchor since I don't know the data you're extracting these numbers from, so they will also match longer numbers (i.e. the first regex would match **1096**0 or 3**1000**).

Comment: Not sure how you did this in three minutes but thanks a lot

Comment: They're not that hard to produce, you just have to write down the values each digit can take. However, they're hard to read and therefore to maintain.

Comment: If I dial 10555 the regex must not work. Shall I put $ at the end of each??

Comment: If the input data consists of the number only, you should add `^` at the start and `$` at the end of every of those regex

Comment: I guess the last one should be `^1(19[3-9]|2([0-7]\d|8[0-8]))$`